# How to json query in a curl POST request

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm trying to send the following query in a curl POST command to an API:

```
{
  "query": [
    {
      "code": "series1",
      "selection": {
        "filter": "item",
        "values": [
          "1",
          "2",
          "3"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "code": "series2",
      "selection": {
        "filter": "item",
        "values": [
          "1",
          "2",
          "3"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "response": {
    "format": "json"
  }
}
```

By now, the only way I got it to work was to hardcode my query like this, using an online [curl-to-PHP](https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/) converter:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\n  \"query\": [\n    {\n      \"code\": \"series1\",\n      \"selection\": {\n        \"filter\": \"item\",\n        \"values\": [\n          \"1\",\n          \"2\",\n          \"3\"\n        ]\n      }\n    },\n    {\n      \"code\": \"series2\",\n      \"selection\": {\n        \"filter\": \"item\",\n        \"values\": [\n          \"1\",\n          \"2\",\n          \"3\"\n        ]\n      }\n    }\n  ],\n  \"response\": {\n    \"format\": \"json\"\n  }\n}\n\n}");
```

Is there a better way to store the query as a variable in a more readable format, and passing this variable to the curl_setopt?

Answer (score 1):

Use array and json-encode:

```
$data = ["query" => "...", "response" => ["format" => "json"]];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
```

upd.: you can try this simple solution

```
function curl(string $method, string $url, array $data = [])
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    if ('POST' === $method) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    }
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return json_decode($response, true);
}
```

and then:

```
curl('POST', 'http://myApi/foo/bar', ['a' => 'b']);
```

Comment: Is there a simple way to convert the query test to an array like in your example?

Comment: @FilipBlaauw `$data = var_export(json_decode('{"query": [{"foo": "bar"}]}', true), true);`